# Java Logger Creates Empty Log Files in Home Directory

Tags: java, logging

I am using a Java Logger in my application with FileHandler set to /DemoApp/AAA.log. 
But my JVM creates empty java.log and java.log.lck files in my home directory every time i run the app.

Does any one have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try loading this property file as the logger configuration:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append=true
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=testlog%u.log

.level=ALL
```

This should output a testlog0.log file to the working directory of the program.
If this does not solve the problem, please provide a minimal example.
Also keep [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1263876/891292) in mind when using directories.