# Opening a relative path and writing

Tags: python, filepath

```
def generate_log(dirname, log_object):
    print(os.path.dirname(__file__),'dfsdfds')
    print(os.listdir())
    for smell in log_object:  
        log = open("../../output/logs/{}_logs".format(smell), "w")
        for elem in log_object[smell]:
            log.write('filename: {}, smelly_lines: {}, metric: {}\n'.format(elem['filename'], str(elem['lineno']), str(elem['metric'])))
```

My function tries to write some logs in to the directory `output/logs/`
The directory that I am calling this function is `C:\Users\user\Desktop\proj\src\Detector`. Since I want the `output` directory to be generated in `/proj` which is my project root, I thought doing `../../` would work, but it gives me

`log = open("../../output/logs/{}_logs".format(smell), "w")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../output/logs/long_method_logs'`

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Yep, use the `logging` library https://stackoverflow.com/a/20667049/5871675

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module with its submodule [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path)

For joining a paths you should do `os.path.join(path1, path2)`

In your case you should do something like this:

```py
log = open(os.path.join(os.pardir, os.pardir, "output", "logs", "{}_logs").format(smell), "w")
```

Also you should `close` this file via `log.close()` before exit

And for this purposes there is a [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am still getting this: `log = open(os.path.join(os.pardir, os.pardir, "output", "logs", "{}_logs").format(smell), "w")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\..\\output\\logs\\long_method_logs'
`

Comment: @Dawn17 may be there are not such directories at paths that you showed us

Comment: I was expecting the directory to be generated when we run that. Are we supposed to make it beforehand?

Comment: @Dawn17 also you should *not* to upvote the answer until you had enough help. Also I want to add that you should create these paths. may be manually may be via `os.mkdir`

Comment: I did not upvote it. So, we are expected to create those folders programmatically before creating the log files?

Comment: I manually created the directories but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Dawn17 may be you should to set the absolute path, because I bet you made the wrong directories due to not obvious CWD. Try to set the absolute path or to get the info about CWD via `print(os.getcwd())` and correct the paths due to that output

Comment: is the `cwd` the directory that I am calling the `open`? Does the path have to be based on `cwd`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192335/discussion-between-mr-morgan-and-dawn17).